# Regex-replace text when text contains more than one dot

Tags: angularjs, regex

I have to make a **regex** that replace text except numbers and **only one dot**
Here is my **regex**::

```
var a = text.replace(/[^0-9,.]/g, '');
```

But it does not replace **dot**. I have to replace **dots** more than one.

here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<input production-qty ID="test"  ng-model="testmodel" type="text"  />
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.directive('productionQty', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
            function fromUser(text) {
                var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9,.]/g, '');
                //var transformedInput = text.matches(/^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?$/g);
                  console.log(transformedInput);
                if (transformedInput !== text) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                    ngModelCtrl.$render();
                }
                return transformedInput;
            }
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
        }
    };
});
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: only one dot means first one? Can you explain with example?

Comment: yes  first one @AvneshShakya

Comment: I have updated the question with code. @AvneshShakya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update 2 :

you can do like this:

```
value.replace(/[\.]/g, function(match, offset, all) { 
     return match === "." ? (all.indexOf(".") === offset ? '.' : '') : ''; 
  })
```

use this [Link](http://jsbin.com/piqahebipe/edit?js,console) for description

update 1 : 
You can do with some trick..

lets replace your first .with some other special character

```
mystring =  mystring.replace(/\./,$)
```

this will update only first dot to $

now update all the dots to blank

```
mystring  = mystring.replace(/\./g,' ')
```

now update that $ to dot

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/\$/g,.)
```

Comment: Thanks. Great Job!   I  have used your Simple Version.  But Self-contained version can be used for more customization.  Thanks again @Jayanti Lal

Comment: Welcome Imran..:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var text = "avnesh112.333.44.55.kaka3443", tempText, a;

var tempText = text.replace( /^([^.]*\.)(.*)$/, function ( a, b, c ) { 
    return b + c.replace( /\./g, '' );
});

a = tempText.replace(/[^0-9,.]/g, '');
```

Not sure, this is only you want or something else.

If yes, it will help.